# Can I do a PhD in Management with an MBA and without a Bachelor's degree?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, supervision, business-school, management

I have dropped out from my Bachelor's studies in Aerospace Engineering after succesfuly completing 1st year.

Then I worked in Marketing, until I became Marketing Director of my company.

I have obtained an non-thesis MBA from a rigorous program at a university ranked among the top 5 in Scotland.

I have realised how much I am interested in the theoretical and research area of Management and I would like to pursue a PhD in management in Germany, Sweden, Norway or Austria, but I am worried that my qualifications, namely the lack of Bachelor's degree and my Master's being non-thesis, may not be sufficient for me to be accepted to a PhD program.

My area of interest is Strategic Moves and Business model patterns and innovation.

In one of my Strategic Planning papers, I was awarded 80% (which is uncommon in the UK) and my lecturer said that he's never seen 80% being awarded before. So I believe I am not bad with the subject knowledge and analytical thinking but I only lack research experience.

Could you please advice if I have any chance? Would any supervisor accept my application ?

Comment: You have to ask them. Unusual cases aren't a good match here.